# Why is Python Terminal on VS Code telling me I'm using Python 2.7.16?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've downloaded the latest version of VS Code and I have the most updated version of Python but I just cannot understand why every time I type `python --version` into the terminal, it tells me I'm working with `2.7.16`. Now I've found a way around this, I've been using an environment which allows me to get to version 3 , invoking it through typing `source env/bin/activate` into the terminal.

I really would like to know how to set the default environment to Python 3 and can't figure out why it won't do that even when it shows `Python 3.11.3 64 bit` in the bottom right hand corner. Even stranger is that when I'm supposedly working on Python version 2, it behaves the same way is 3 e.g. If I request the type of unicode using u' , it'll give me a string back and not unicode. So here it behaves like Python 3 but when I want to download pip/ BeautifulSoup, it tells me my Python version is too old.

So I can just keep creating a Python 3 environment but I think I should really know how to set it as default.

I tried to locate where Python 3 is through the terminal and then update the JSON user settings with this location but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Well, you **should** be using virtual environments. But anyway, it sounds like there is something weird going on with the terminal environment in vscode, but you are going to have to give use more specifics. This is actually a case where *screenshots* would help (generally, avoid screenshots, but in this case, we would want to see what your VSCode is actually showing)

Comment: And also, please provide **as much detail as possible**. For example, you say "I tried to locate where Python 3 is through the terminal and then update the JSON user settings with this location but it didn't make a difference." **what does that mean precisely**? What did you do, exactly?

Comment: "Even stranger is that when I'm supposedly working on Python version 2, it behaves the same way is 3 eg. If if I request the type of unicode using u' , it'll give me a string back and not unicode. " So again, what does this mean precisely? What are you doing? How are you running the code?

Comment: the fact that the VSC status bar mentions a Python version means that `python` in the terminal is of the same version, they have nothing to do with each other, execute a python script with a launch config and you see how VSC use the Python version

Comment: you most likely are on a Mac and that has Python 2.x installed as part of the OS, it uses Python 2.x scripts, use a different command like `python3` or the full path of the python 3.x interpreter in the terminal, don't be tempted to write Python 2.x code

Comment: @rioV8 I mean, the correct solution is to use virtual environments. Which they have already done.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, sorry for being too vague. It's quite hard to screenshot as it's more a lack of things happening if that makes sense. It's more anytime I try (without creating a virtual environment which does work) it will tell me that the Python I have is python 2.7.16 
So what I did try was typing 'which python3' into the terminal to find out where the python 3 is located. 
it gave back this: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
I then went to preferences open user settings JSON and added it into the python path there 
(code in next comment)

Comment: {
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3",
    "python.pythonPath": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3",
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false

So I made this the code for preferences open user settings (JSON) hoping it would make my default version python 3 but still when I searched in the terminal python --version, it gave back version 2. Is there a method I'm missing? 
I'm very new so maybe a bit slow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using Mac, even if you install Python 3, the Python 2 that comes with Mac is still intact.

You can solve this problem by using a [virtualenv](https://peps.python.org/pep-0405/).

```
virtualenv --python=python3.11.3 .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
```

If you do not want to use a virtual environment and only want to display the Python version correctly, you can modify the alias in bash_profile.

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

vi ~/.bash_profile  
alias python='/usr/local/bin/python3'
```

Then reload bash_profile

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is maybe an issue with VSCode

You didn't activated the virtual environnement.

Normally, VSCode should automatically start the venv.

[[image: Example]]

If the issue persists, you can try to run a similar command

Comment: Hey, Wlink, putting the image in here can be helpful, but you don't want to rely on the image itself having the full scope if the answer (in this case, what command to enter to activate the venv). If the image itself is lost, the answer is lost. Even if it isn't lost, the image isn't accessible to search or to accessibility tools like screenreaders.

Comment: Yeah ik, I answered kind of quickly. Thanks for pointing it out!